# Add namespace pcl functions and PointT in header file

Tags: c++, namespaces, ros, point-cloud-library

I have a header file `preprocess.h` in the include folder that simply does noise removal from a point cloud. The point type of point cloud does not exist in the pcl library so I have to create a custom point type `RadarPoint` for `pcl::PointCloud<PointT>`. Also, it's a good practice to create a namespace for functions inside the header file. The following is my code.

```
#ifndef PREPROCESS_H
#define PREPROCESS_H

#define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/pcl_macros.h>
#include <pcl/filters/statistical_outlier_removal.h>


namespace filtration {
    
    struct RadarPoint {
      PCL_ADD_POINT4D;                  // preferred way of adding a XYZ+padding
      uint8_t beam_side;
      EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW    // make sure our new allocators are aligned
    } EIGEN_ALIGN16;                    // enforce SSE padding for correct memory alignment
    
    POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (RadarPoint,           // here we add XYZ and beam_side
                                       (float, x, x)
                                       (float, y, y)
                                       (float, z, z)
                                       (uint8_t, beam_side, beam_side)
    )
    
    //remove outliers from point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<RadarPoint>::Ptr filter(const pcl::PointCloud<RadarPoint>::Ptr& cloud_input);
    
}
    
#endif
```

However, there are some bugs. For the function, I got the error `"namespace filtration::pcl" has no member PointCloud`. For the custom `PointT`, I got the two errors. The first error is `namespace "filtration::pcl" has no member "Vector3fMap"` for the code `PCL_ADD_POINT4D;`. The second error is `improperly terminated macro invocation` for the code `POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT`. Any help on why and how to solve them?

Comment: Need to see more of the code to see where your issue is. From the code above   "pcl::PointCloud<RadarPoint>::Ptr filter" is declared but not implemented, but I assume this is done in cpp file somewhere? Also all your macros we have no way of knowing if you did them correctly, POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT looks very strange compared to standard C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT` must be used in the global namespace: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/common/include/pcl/register_point_struct.h#L63

See also how the macro is used in PCL: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp#L1781